# How to add label to scrollview

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

i am doing a  small on concept on how to add label to scrollview . I have written a code

but my app is terminating .but i can't understand it why it is terminating .can any one help in solving this problem....my application is terminating at inserting at third label..

```
int y=0;
NSMutableArray *languageArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Chinese",@"Spanish",@"English",@"Arabic",@"Hindi",@"Bengali",@"Portuguese",@"Russian",@"Japanese",@"German",nil];
UILabel *languageLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, y ,90,30 )];

for(int i=0;i<[languageArray count];i++)
{

    NSLog(@"array count is @%d",[languageArray count]);
    languageLabel.text=[languageArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"array objectat index is @%@",[languageArray objectAtIndex:i]);
    languageLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:19.0];
    languageLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [languageScrollView addSubview:languageLabel];
    //  [languageScrollView addSubview:languageLabel];
    //y+=90;        
    y+=languageLabel.frame.size.height;
    [languageLabel release];
}

[languageScrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
[languageScrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];

[languageScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(genderScrollView.frame.size.width, y)];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with below modified code

```
     int y=0;
     NSMutableArray *languageArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Chinese",@"Spanish",@"English",@"Arabic",@"Hindi",@"Bengali",@"Portuguese",@"Russian",@"Japanese",@"German",nil]; 


                    for(int i=0;i<[languageArray count];i++)
                    {
                      UILabel *languageLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, y ,90,30 )];
                        NSLog(@"array count is @%d",[languageArray count]);
                        languageLabel.text=[languageArray objectAtIndex:i];
                        NSLog(@"array objectat index is @%@",[languageArray objectAtIndex:i]);
                        languageLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:19.0];
                        languageLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
                        [languageScrollView addSubview:languageLabel];
                    //  [languageScrollView addSubview:languageLabel];
                        //y+=90;        
                        y+=languageLabel.frame.size.height;
                        [languageLabel release];

                    }
```